# What are the possible values for startElement function in DefaultHandler class

Tags: excel, attributes, apache-poi, saxparser, xssf

I have been trying to use **XSSF and SAX event API** as it is mentioned in [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) to read a large excel file. They have used several key words as c, r, t, s when calling getValue() function as it is shown in below code.

```
if(name.equals("c")) {
            // Print the cell reference
            System.out.print(attributes.getValue("r") + " - ");
            // Figure out if the value is an index in the SST
            String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");
            if(cellType != null && cellType.equals("s")) {
                nextIsString = true;
            } else {
                nextIsString = false;
            }
        }
```

I need to figure out possible characters I can use and any description as to when and where to use it. I have been searching through the net to find a clear description about possible key words for queName ('name' as it is mentioned here) and attributes. But I was unable to find a clear description.

Appreciate if anyone can explain it bit more. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found simple explanation from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945959/how-to-evaluate-a-excel-formula-through-xssf-event-api). But, still the other possible tags that can be used and how to generate a xml file as below is a question.

```
<c r="B10">
   <f>SUM(B1:B9)</f>
   <v>4995</v>
</c>
```